# Publisher/Subscriber in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, publish-subscribe

**Problem:**

```
    IEnumerable<Signal> feed = GetFeed();

var average1 = feed.MovingAverage(10);
var average2 = feed.MovingAverage(20);

var zipped = average1.Zip(average2, (x,y) => Tuple.Create(x,y));
```

When I iterate through "zipped", GetFeed().GetEnumerator() gets called twice and creates all sorts of synchronization issues. Is there a LINQ operator that can be used to broadcast values from single producer to multiple consumers? I know about Memoize, but in my case I can't predict buffer size to keep slow and fast consumers "happy".

I am thinking about writing my own operator that would keep separate queues for each consumer, but wanted to check if there is an existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896). It's like LINQ to Objects, but in reverse: you don't *pull* values, they're *pushed* through observers.

It takes a little while to get used to it, but judging by what you've posted, it's exactly the right model for you.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking at Rx. It has Publish() that covers this scenario. But, unfortunately there are other issues that prevent me from relying on it 100%. It does take some time to get used to it, which could create problems with bringing other developers up to speed.

Comment: @Serge: You could always create your own equivalent, just for as much as you need - which may well be simpler. I did something like that a while ago; it was much less elegant than Rx, but I found it easier to understand at the time :)

Comment: Ironically, after a day of prototyping I am back to take a deeper look at Rx. Push model looks more appropriate for my scenario... less blocking